# How to use image button to expand and collapse content

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to convert this to image button:

```
[bg_collapse view="button-green" color="#4a4949" icon="arrow" expand_text="Show Positions" collapse_text="Hide Positions" ]
 content
 content
 content
[/bg_collapse]
```

Comment: what is this, some type of shortcode?

Comment: @AshleyBrown, hi. Yes, I will like to edit the code to allow us to use image as button instead of regular button.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: So then just remove the text content and insert an image inside the anchor? Create a new parameter on that shortcode to accept an image url or something

Comment: @AshleyBrown, I found precisely what I have been looking for here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-collapse-o-matic/

Thanks for your responses.